# Is it possible to return JWT token from AAD B2C for SAML IdP?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, saml, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Need to connect a SAML 2.0 IdP via AAD B2C and  to be returned JWT token format, not SAML.

Answer (score 0):

We have connected a SAML 2.0 IdP (ADFS) to a B2C policy and returned a JWT to applications from it, so yes it is possible.
The policy gets claims from the IdP response; the token that it forms for the application is completely separate from this.

At least in custom policies configuring a claims provider is completely separate from configuring the token issuer technical profile.

Links from comments:

This page shows how ADFS is added as an example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-adfs2016-custom?tabs=app-reg-ga. Note the SAML technical profile does not have an output token format. That's because it outputs claims to the claims bag that the next steps can see, not a token. The token is generated by the last step in the user journey.

This also shows how SAML integrations can work in B2C: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/connect-with-saml-service-providers. The critical bit is that SAML can be used between apps and B2C if desired and/or between B2C and an identity provider. The protocols used in App -> B2C and B2C -> IdP can be completely different.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. (I tried to set output token format like JWT for SAML technical profile but doesn't help)

Comment: This page shows how ADFS is added as an example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-adfs2016-custom?tabs=app-reg-ga. Note the SAML technical profile does not have an output token format. That's because it outputs _claims_ to the claims bag that the next steps can see, not a token. The token is generated by the last step in the user journey.

Comment: This also shows how SAML integrations can work in B2C: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/connect-with-saml-service-providers. The critical bit is that SAML can be used between apps and B2C if desired and/or between B2C and an identity provider. The protocols used in App -> B2C and B2C -> IdP can be completely different.

Comment: @juunas - seems like those links should be part of the answer, or your rewrite of the steps contained therein.

Comment: **Thanks**, I started integration with second link, for now I set new provider (from Microsoft  SAML test) and leave same journey how was before (just add new provider like button). Now I'm trying to signin but get another issue discussed on stack overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62736038/azure-ad-adfs-gving-error-aadb2c90168-the-http-redirect-request-does-not-conta)